# Do not share static properties in tests

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, .net-core, xunit.net

I have to write tests for existing code with xUnit. Here is a simplified problem I faced with:

```
using Xunit;

namespace XUnitTestProject1
{
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            GlobalHanler.StaticProperty = "some value";
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Test2()
        {
            Assert.Null(GlobalHanler.StaticProperty);
        }
    }

    public static class GlobalHanler
    {
        public static string StaticProperty;
    }
}
```

GlobalHandler owns another object, both are static

When I run 2 tests together, `Test2` fails because it can see the value that was set in `Test1`.
However, when I run `Test2` separately, it succeeds.

My goal is to make 2 tests pass when they run together. I need somehow to reset global static property for each test separately, but I can't change the implementation of `GlobalHandler`

Setting `StaticProperty` in each test method seems not an option, because it will affect other tests running in parallel

Comment: If you can't do anything about how `GlobalHandler` is implemented, then you'll have to only run one of these tests at a time.

Comment: Since static objects are shared across app domain, you can create an appdomain at test setup, load the code with static objects, and unload at cleanup. But it's very ugly workaround

Answer (score 2):

In order to have testable code, you should first put  the logic in a class that can be created as many times as needed and then use that class across your code by passing the reference.

Your production code can always use a singleton, but having no direct references to the singleton makes it testable.

Singletons and testing do not cohabit very well due to the possible side effects and unclear dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using `static`. Instead of this, create a simple class and register it in your DI container as a singleton. Then you can test it easily.

Simple example:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton<IQueueUrlProvider, QueueUrlProvider>()
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        Console.WriteLine(serviceProvider.GetService<IQueueUrlProvider>().QueueUrl);
    }

    public interface IQueueUrlProvider
    {
        string QueueUrl { get; }
    }

    public class QueueUrlProvider : IQueueUrlProvider
    {
        private readonly Lazy<string> _getQueueUrlLazy;
        public string QueueUrl => _getQueueUrlLazy.Value;
        public QueueUrlProvider()
        {
            _getQueueUrlLazy = new Lazy<string>(GetQueueUrl);
        }

        private string GetQueueUrl()
        {
            // get url here
            return "your queue url";
        }
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/JjRh4q